# How to use latest version in itunesconnect of the app when you have 3 or more versions

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, app-store-connect, application-loader

Well due to legal issue, Apple took time to upload my app. Meanwhile i was providing legal documentation to Apple, I uploaded two more versions. Versions numbers are 1.0.0, 1.1.0 and 1.3.0. Now Apple has reviewed Legal documents and approved version 1.0.0 but I want apple to use 1.3.0 which is more optimized.

I am attaching an image for further clarification

[image]

I want version 1.3.0 to be used rather than 1.0.0

Apple store link is https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pitelevision/id899221779?ls=1&mt=8

Comment: You will have to submit a new version for review and select the 1.3 build. Then you will have to wait until Apple reviews this version.

Comment: This solved my problem. I thought it will be picked up automatically.

Comment: No, with the new iTunesConnect you can upload mutiple builds and sent them to test users. Therefor you now need to select the build you want to the version update.